# 404 not found on client website on Mac only - works on other computers, smartphones, tablets

Tags: dns, http-status-code-404

I created a website based on wordpress with a custom theme setup. The live website renders fine on every computer, smartphone and tablet i've tried, except for my Mac, which I use as my local development machine. I have tried various browsers on my mac. The off-line development version renders fine.

When I visit the website http://www.redroselimos.com/ I get the following error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

I suspect it is a DNS issue or perhaps a Mac configuration issue?

Mac OSX 10.7.4
Chrome 22.0.1229.79
MAMP PRO 2.0.5
DNS: 208.67.222.222/208.67.220.220 (openDNS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it shows up fine on every other machine then the site is validly there and it can only be a networking issue for your Mac. Most likely as it is your dev setup you have other settings in place. The 404 error means you are at least reaching a webserver, so you are getting out to the internet. There are a few things you can do:

1. You could check your `/etc/hosts` file to see if you send that domain to another IP - which would be my first suspicion.
2. Also check the `httpd.conf` on the server to see if you handle your dev machine's IP differently, or if it's rerouted in `.htaccess`.
3. You can also try `tail -f /var/log/httpd/access_log` or whatever your log file is and then try hitting it again from your Mac and see what comes through.
4. Try going through a proxy from your Mac to your site. proxify.com and hidemyass.com both work for this, that way you'll see if it's strictly an IP issue.

This should point out exactly what the error is.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help on this!!

Your first suggestion to check the hosts file worked. There was a line in there: 127.0.0.1 redroselimos.com

I followed the instructions for editing the hosts file from this site: http://decoding.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-in-mac-os-x-leopard/

Answer (score 0):

I have Mac, Lion 10.7.5, Safari 6.0.1

no error. Surfed to the link you wrote, I can see the site (top left a form to login, center header a kind of gallery, some other stuff in the center)

I have no special configuration, only default. If you didn't change the configuration before that is not the problem. If you do, try to restore the default settings.

I think that is a problem with localhost, because you want to surf to your pc from the outside being inside. I don't see a valid reason to do that, if your mac is the host of the site you just need to surf to localhost.

By the way, there is an update to version 10.7.5 for Lion

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I haven't changed anything since the site went live and it has never worked for me on this Mac.

I read there was a bug with 10.7.5 on the Mac Pro's.....

Answer (score 0):

**What causes the Hosts File 404 Error in Mac OS X**

The Hosts File is found on the user's computer machine. It is not found using the Search or Finder function. It is woven into the machine code.

The hosts file is used to map DOMAIN hostnames to IP NUMBER addresses. Example: MyDomain.com shown in browser is really a number on the internet 111.11.11.11

This map process is called "resolving" the browser alpha letter name into the numerical number address used by the internet.

Most hosts files do not have many entries because most browser name entries are resolved in DNS lookup tables provided to the user by the internet provider.

A hosts file can cause the local computer machine to present a **404 Cannot Find Page** error. This is because a webpage domain entry is in the list that is wrong or it is out of date.

One day the domain entry was correctly shown to be 222.22.22.22 but really it has been changed to 333.33.33.33

Another computer machine will go to 333.33.33.33 without any problem because there is an up-to-date listing in the local machine's hosts file. Or there is not even an entry.

So, the local computer hosts file needs to correct the error. To stop the 404 error. This is done by editing the local machine's host file. The bad out-of-date entry needs to be is updated. Or the entry is needs to be completely removed from the hosts file.

If the entry is completely removed from the hosts file then the internet provider just sends the local computer machine to a internet DNS file to "resolve" the browser alpha letter entry into a numerical interet address

Instructions for editing the hosts file are here: [How to Edit the Hosts File in Mac OS X with Terminal](https://osxdaily.com/2012/08/07/edit-hosts-file-mac-os-x/). Knowing how to use Terminal is required.

Comment: Thanks for the info!